# rails rails3-jquery-autocomplete MissingAttributeError for display_value

Tags: autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem to autocomplete the name of a user, search attribute is lastname but I want to display full name as the display value. Here's what I have in my controller

```
autocomplete :customer, :lastname, :display_value => :display_autocomplete
```

Customer Model

```
def display_autocomplete
   self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
end
```

Error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: firstname):
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get the extra data, like so:

```
autocomplete :customer, :lastname, :display_value => :display_autocomplete, :extra_data => [:firstname, :lastname]
```

Comment: Thanks for solution it worked fine except did have to make slight change in display_autocomplete method "#{self.first_name}" + ' ' + "#{self.last_name}" or else I got "String can't be coerced into Fixnum"